# res.redirect() is throwing error on opening up a s3 URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have a class **S3Download** which is fetching the URL of an image file from the *S3* bucket and when I do a log of the URL in the same file then the image is getting downloaded upon clicking the URL from the console whereas when I return the URL and do `res.redirect(URL)` or clicking the URL from the *console.log* in the **index.js** file(which is containing the routes) then it is showing the following error in the browser:

> **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**
>
> ```xml
> <Error>
> <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
> <Message>
> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
> </Message>
> <RequestId>AAD90E10F9642E33</RequestId>
> <HostId>
> aV3WPRpYPjK8kUreukEZFbBV0KKECS6YdVViNEaA/dK0P5/hVrVX3yQd/k0kqWSl1PPuEuC7M0M=
> </HostId>
> </Error>
> ```

---

**S3Download** helper class:

```
class S3Download {
    constructor(app, response) {
        this.app = app
        this.response = response
    }

    downloadFaster(file) {
        const s3 = this.app.s3

        const options = {
            Bucket: 'filesharingapp',
            Key: file.filename,
            Expires: 3600
        }

        const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', options)
        console.log('s3Download fasterDownload url ==> ', url)

        return url
    }
}

module.exports = {
    S3Download
}
```

---

**index.js**

Calling the following code inside a route

```
const downloader = new S3Download(router, res)
        const fileUrl = downloader.downloadFaster(result)

        console.log('fileUrl ==> ', fileUrl)

        return res.redirect(fileUrl)
```

I am not sure what wrong is happening here either this is the problem with AWS S3 or I am a noob in Node.JS

**Edit 1: 06-MAY-2019**
Now, both the URLs are working fine and opening up the image but `res.redirect` is still giving the error. Can anyone give any insight into why S3 is throwing the error on `res.redirect`?

Comment: Seems like you need  to use AWS sigv4 for creating signed urls, currently the code is generating signed url using sigv2 which may not be supported in the region where bucket exist and it is going to deprecated anyway.

Comment: @JamesDean I would switch to sigv4 but for now, both the URLs should have returned the error as per your statement but why only one of them is returning the error?